# Tilde in listings using lineskip and a command breaks "onehalfspace"

Tags: macros, listings, tilde

I'm trying to produce an inline code snippet that starts with a `~`.

Using `onehalfspacing` per university requirement and `lineskip=-1pt` for subjectively better legibility, packing the `\lstinline` inside a command shortcut destroys the spacing in all future sections.

Why does this occur? How is the command version parsed differently than what the command is supposed to be a shortcut for? I suspect it has something to do with how `~` is parsed inside a command?

Removing the `lineskip` or placing any character in front of the `~` fixes this issue, but isn't desirable for me.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\lstset{
    lineskip=-1pt,
    literate={~} {$\sim$}{1}
}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Inline}
\lstinline{~1}\\
\blindtext

\section{No tilde}
\code{FIX ~1}\\
\blindtext

\section{Tilde breaks everything}
\code{~1}\\
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure why, but

```
\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline}
```

with no change in the document code fixes the problem.

Well, there are some clues: with your definition, `~` is tokenized before being passed to `\lstinline` and this is probably the issue.

Comment: Is there a way to de-tokenize it, so to speak?

Comment: @TobiasWeiß Why should you define `\code` to take an argument?

Comment: Your approach works flawlessly in the MWE. New issue: When it's inside a `tabular` environment, using your approach throws a "Missing } inserted" error. Should I update the MWE or ask that as a new question?

Comment: @TobiasWeiß Use `\code|...|` (where `|` stands for any character not in the code you want to typeset). That's a standard problem with `\lstinline`.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly, I had just found that in an ancient post here. `$` seems to work as well. Still - using my first approach with the argument in place worked even in `tabular`s. Do you suppose there's a workaround to just get a working code snippet everywhere with the same command, or is that just one of LaTeX's "features"?

Comment: @TobiasWeiß It's a `\lstinline` feature.